# Pergunta sobre a API do Stack Exchange pode ser feita aqui ou somente no Stack Apps?

Tags: suporte

**Minha pergunta é:**

Perguntas relacionadas diretamente a *API do Stack Exchange* podem ser feitas no Stackoverflow  ou somente no [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=active)? Digo isso porque lá a pergunta deve ser feita em  inglês, diferente do [Stack Overflow em Portugues](http://pt.stackoverflow.com).

**Motivo:**

Estou com uma ideia, que não vem ao caso, mas encontrei uma API do Stack Exchange.

Essa API pode ser [visualizada aqui](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). Nesse mesmo link possui como registrar o aplicativo e isso faz com que entre no https://stackapps.com/, um outro site do Stack Exchange.

Nesse mesmo site, além de registrar e visualizar outros apps, você tem o "forum", similar ao Stack Overflow, porém focado em tal API.

Comment: Acho que pode ser feita no sopt sim, a API é documentada e tem haver com programação :) - No stackapps.com vocë pode tirar duvidas, mas é principalmente voltado pra divulgar, então acho o SOpt um bom lugar sim pra perguntas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Stack Overflow tem umas 9000 perguntas por dia. É bastante pergunta. Por conta disso, vários assuntos foram gradualmente recebendo novas casas na rede  pra tentar desafogar o SOen, ao mesmo tempo que oferece à essas perguntas uma chance muito melhor de obterem respostas. Elas não tem mais que competir com outras 9000 perguntas pela atenção da comunidade.

Esse foi o caso de diversos sites - [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), etc. - e é o caso do Stack Apps. Não foi o assunto que se tornou *não relevante* ao site mas sim que, dado o tamanho, fazia mais sentido dar uma casa própria do que continuar vivendo sob o mesmo teto.

Nós não temos nenhum desses problemas. Nem temos 9000 perguntas/dia e nem temos uma quantidade desproporcional de perguntas sobre a API do Stack Exchange. Então não há motivo algum para precisarmos da mesma solução.
A solução no nosso caso é justamente a mais óbvia: pode perguntar no SOpt à vontade.